# How to access value of nested Struct data in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I am new to C programming, Need help in access this value "data" in below "sum" method.

```
BigInteger sum(BigInteger A, BigInteger B) {
    long data = A -> list ->headnode->data
}
```

**List.h**

```
typedef struct ListObj* List;
```

**List.c**

```
    typedef struct NodeObj {
       long data;
       struct NodeObj* next;
       struct NodeObj* last;

    } NodeObj;

    typedef NodeObj* Node;
    typedef struct ListObj {
        Node cursor;
        Node headnode;
        Node lastnode;
    } ListObj;
```

**BigInteger.h**

```
typedef struct BigIntegerObj* BigInteger;
```

**BigInteger.c**

```
typedef struct BigIntegerObj {
     int sign;
     struct List list;

} BigIntegerObj;
```

Comment: Looks fine except for a missing ; at the end. Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to compile?  Also, it's generally bad practice to hide pointers behind a typedef as it can cause confusion as to what is actually a pointer.

Comment: You've declared **opaque** pointers in List.h and BigInteger.h. That means that you can only access the members of `BigIntegerObj` in file BigInteger.c, and you can only access the members of `ListObj` in file List.c.

Comment: getting error : Incomplete definition of type 'struct ListObj'

Comment: The line `struct List list;` in BigInteger.c is not correct. `List` is a typedef for a pointer. So I think you meant `List list;`

Comment: List a1 = A->list;
        List b1 = B->list;
        
        int data =a1->headnode->data;

Comment: Please help and suggest fix.

Comment: Suggested fix: remove out all typedefs. Use the structure definitions everywhere. Make it work. When it works then see if you can replace them with tyepdefs again